# "I did not complain and tell/told myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem."

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> I did not complain and tell myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem.

Or:

> I did not complain and told myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem.

Some notes:

- I want to mean that I did not complain, and I did tell myself to calm down, instead of complaining and not telling myself to calm down.

I don't know whether I should use told or tell in this sentence. Since "complain" is present tense, I should be using "tell", right? But it sounds (to me) weird to be using tell. But if I use "complained" it seems wrong...?

Comment: *"and[ so ]I told myself to calm down ..."* The words in your sentence bump into each other because the second sentence needs a pronoun.

Comment: I agree, especially since it negates "complain", and it should be made clear that it doesn't want to negate "told myself to calm down."

Comment: _Complain_ here is **not** the present tense, it is the basic form of the verb used with _did_ to make a past tense in the negative.

Comment: _Complain_ is the bare infinitive, used with “did not” to form a negative past emphatic.  It might be more more obvious in third-person: “he did not complain”.  If it were mere present tense, it would be “he did not complains”.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to point out that "complain" in your given sentence is **not** present tense because it relies on the **I did**.

You did *not* complain, but you did tell yourself to calm down, so for that to work, you will need to use a comma to separate them.

So the correct sentence would be:

> I did not complain, and told myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem.